# Unlocking XNA game update rate and preventing unnecessary Draw calls and heavy logic Updates

Tags: xna, c#, frame-rate

I had some input problems which can be partially solved by unlocking game update rate. Now the input updates as fast as possible, but the game also calls the main `Draw` method a lot too. I believe there are some calls that may be omitted without causing any noticeable problems, and I'd like to know how I can do it.

I tried using code similar to frame rate counter code, but it just doesn't work. It either doesn't skip frames, or skips them all. Here it is:

```
double time = 0;
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    double frameRate = 1.0 / 60;
    time += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    if (time > frameRate)
    {
        time = time % frameRate;
    // the rest of the draw call
```

When the game window is active, only dark purple color is visible I guess that's application's default background color when nothing is being drawn. When the game window is not active, frame rate drops from infinity (though I get about 4000 fps) to around 50 (which is unusual, since the default frame rate is 60, but it's not an issue).

If I set `frameRate` value to lower than 1/50 (like 1/10) it becomes obvious that draw calls are skipped and the dark purple background is visible (and resources are being saved), but only when the window is inactive. So the game behaves as expected, but only when it is not in focus, which is not the way it is supposed to be played :)

How do I fix this?

I'd like to extend this to work on heavy logic updates, so they too are not done more than enough times per second. The game should only update input as fast as possible, and I believe, reducing the number of logic update and draw calls frees up resources for input update to use, increasing their frequency.

---

This is how I ended up doing this:

```
double interval = 1d / 60; // draw and do heavy updates only 60 frames per second
double time;

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    LightUpdate(gameTime);

    time += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    if (time > interval)
        time = time % interval; // or while (time > interval) time -= interval;
    else
    {
        SuppressDraw();
        base.Update(gameTime);
        return;
    }

    HeavyUpdate(gameTime);
}
```

Saves frames, light update rate rose from 2k to **110k** @100Hz which is a tremendous success!

Comment: What is the underlying issue you're trying to solve? What causes input to not work when updates and draws run at the same frame rate? Tinkering with XNA's internal timing might cause unforseen issues. Edit: also is base.Draw() inside the `if` statement in the code you posted?

Comment: The issue is too broad to fit in one question and partially unsolvable, but part of it is, by increasing input polling rate, which I am trying to do in this question. If you know a better way to poll input devices as fast as the OS does, please let me know. There is no `base.Draw()` inside the Draw method, as it doesn't appear necessary in any of my game projects.

Comment: I think that I have never seen game that would need faster input updates then 60 times per second. Are you sure you are not trying to do something like inputing text based on keyboard states (instead of from winapi message loop)?

Comment: Part of my game's base mechanic is precise mouse input. Text input is done via capturing key state changes.

Comment: Are you working with actual human users, because I find it unlikely that a human can move a mouse accurately so fast that a 60x per second polling rate is not accurate enough. I know of no FPS games (arguably the fastest mouse movements happen there) with a separate 'input loop' to solve such a problem.

Comment: Well, then I know one framework by Microsoft that indubitably causes different problems with input, for one there is no normal text input by default. I really do have a problem, and this question is aimed at solving one part of it. Nobody can tell me what the source of the lag problem is, so I found one way to solve it — increase frame rate, specifically unlock it and let the game do the maximum number of update and draw calls. Now that the lag is almost unnoticeable, I'd like to save some CPU and GPU by dropping frame draws that are not visible, leaving only calls within display refresh rate.

Comment: It's worth pointing out, for the sake of completeness, that input must be done on the main thread.

Comment: [This answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4236431/165500) gives some more details about what's going on. Dadoo Games has posted the correct answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know in your Update method that you don't need or want to render anything simply call SupressDraw() on your game object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.suppressdraw.aspx). You don't need to add any additional logic into your Draw method to handle this, and your frame skipping logic can be moved into your Update call.

Comment: This solved one part of my problem, the other I will post in my question.

Answer (score -3):

For one I would not be using doubles in a modulus operation because 1/60th can't be represented exactly in a double variable and neither will the time accumulation so you will be getting a fair bit of round off error and due to that, some interesting results.

What I would do, if you simply have to do this, is to calculate your 1/60th constant outside of this loop, assign your time variable to that value initially, and then decrement it by elapsedTime in each draw call. When the time variable is equal to or below zero then do your draw and then add the 1/60th time to it. You will still get a minor amount of round off/up error but that should balance out between draw calls.

Comment: I put it inside a frequently called method for easy debugging. Didn't think it could cause bugs on its own.

Comment: Well that would be my first suspicion. Its not the assignment of the 1/60th that is the problem(I just wouldnt put calculation of constants into the draw loop) rather that modulus that I am more skeptical of. You may want to explore exactly what elapsedTime values you are getting.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work unless the game window is inactive. I wonder which variables change when the window activates.

Comment: What I don't get is is it my fault with math and logic, or is it something else, like draw calls at certain moments of time won't be drawn to screen. If the game does 2400 main Draw calls, maybe it is programmed to automatically filter too frequent calls.

Comment: -1 it is unlikely that this is a precision/round off error and he is already comparing using '>' so a slight error is not a problem. The worst case is that the average FPS for this game would be slightly less than the target FPS but we're talking a differences of a few hundredths of a millisecond here which is precision which is already impossible in a non-realtime environment.

Comment: Perhaps you should look around a bit before commenting RoyT there are plenty of articles about strange results when using modulus and doubles. Here is one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925223/floating-point-arithmetic-modulo-operator-on-double-type

Comment: Certainly `time = time % frameRate` should be `time = time - frameRate`, but that doesn't actually solve the problem in the OP.

Comment: Well since there was a lack of code or details supplied I made my best assertion with what was provided. Why is it so much easier to shoot down a suggestion than to provide a constructive alternative. After all I was just trying to help and one way to do that is to eliminate possible problem areas. After many many years of programming one thing I have learned is to not ignore the seemingly minor details.

Comment: Nobody says details aren't important. I just know I can live with whatever small fraction of time gets miscalculated, there will be ways to fix it. The code in the question is all I have. Changing time counting logic didn't help. If you know a better, and more importantly *working* way to do what I want to do, please let me know.

Comment: I am happy that DadooGames and Andrew were able to dig up a partial solution for you; after all that is what this is all for. I only take issue with people that bash other peoples efforts without offering their own constructive suggestions. I would much rather upvote a better answer then downvote someone who is suggesting something to try regardless of wether it panned out or not.

Comment: @RobCurr for that we have comments, answers are supposed to answer the question